# Mito installation in Anaconda Environment

Tags: python

I am trying to install Mito (low code spreadsheet option) into an Anaconda environment. I have managed to create the package and I am running it locally on my machine.

When I try and install it gives me the error in hte last line and I have added all the steps that I followed to get to this point

```
conda activate mitoenv
[Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.]
pip install mitoinstaller
[Requirement already satisfied: mitoinstaller in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (0.0.107)Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from mitoinstaller) (0.4.4)

Requirement already satisfied: termcolor in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from mitoinstaller) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: analytics-python in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from mitoinstaller) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>2.1 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: monotonic>=1.5 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.7 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backoff==1.10.0 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.7->analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.7->analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.7->analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\osjmuller\anaconda_latest\envs\mitoenv\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.7->analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (3.3)]


python -m pip install mitoinstaller:

  File "C:\Users\OSJMUL~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18156/784919668.py", line 1
    python -m pip install mitoinstaller
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you erroneously added `:` at the end of last command. From the [documentation](https://docs.trymito.io/getting-started/installing-mito/installing-mito-inside-a-virtual-environment):

```
conda create -n mitoenv python=3.8
conda activate mitoenv
python -m pip install mitoinstaller
python -m mitoinstaller install
```

However, I had some errors after `python -m pip install mitoinstaller` due to missing dependencies:

```
(mitoenv) luca@ASUS-ROG:~$ pip install mitoinstaller
Collecting mitoinstaller
  Using cached mitoinstaller-0.0.122-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting termcolor
  Using cached termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mitoinstaller) (0.4.4)
Collecting analytics-python
  Using cached analytics_python-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting requests<3.0,>=2.7
  Using cached requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting monotonic>=1.5
  Using cached monotonic-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting backoff==1.10.0
  Using cached backoff-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from analytics-python->mitoinstaller) (2.8.1)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Installing collected packages: termcolor, monotonic, certifi, urllib3, six, idna, charset-normalizer, backoff, requests, analytics-python, mitoinstaller
ERROR: pips dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.                                                                                            
requests-oauthlib 1.3.0 requires oauthlib>=3.0.0, which is not installed.                                                            
pandas 1.2.2 requires pytz>=2017.3, which is not installed.                                                                          
oauth2client 4.1.3 requires httplib2>=0.9.1, which is not installed.                                                                 
moto 1.3.16.dev122 requires MarkupSafe<2.0, which is not installed.                                                                  
moto 1.3.16.dev122 requires more-itertools, which is not installed.                                                                  
moto 1.3.16.dev122 requires pytz, which is not installed.                                                                            
moto 1.3.16.dev122 requires zipp, which is not installed.                                                                            
google-api-core 1.26.3 requires packaging>=14.3, which is not installed.                                                             
google-api-core 1.26.3 requires pytz, which is not installed.                                                                        
Successfully installed analytics-python-1.4.0 backoff-1.10.0 certifi-2021.10.8 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 idna-3.3 mitoinstaller-0.0.122 monotonic-1.6 requests-2.27.1 six-1.16.0 termcolor-1.1.0 urllib3-1.26.8
```

for which I had to first install manually the missing packages:

```
pip install mitoinstaller
pip install requests-oauthlib
pip install oauth2client
pip install pandas
pip install moto
```

and finally `python -m mitoinstaller install` worked.